# How can I contiuously monitor a Mac OS process for a spinning beach ball state?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging

How can I continuously monitor a Mac OS process for a [spinning beach ball state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel), and then log debugging information when the beach ball happens?  This monitoring process will need to be active as the machine is coming out of a sleep state.

It appears that Apple has radically changed its debugging tools over time, and most of the information I'm finding is for obsolete tools that are not longer present in Mac OS X or XCode.

I understand that I will probably need to use XCode for this, but I don't have a lot of experience with Mac OS development nor will I likely have to debug a process like this in the future.

I am using Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.3 (18D109) and have XCode 10.1 (10B61).

Comment: Can you clarify whether your intent is to monitor any application for a beachball state, or whether you are only monitoring a particular app that you are developing (and hence have access to that app's code)?

Comment: @RhysLewis My intent is to monitor any application, or a particular application that I do **not** have the code for.